# Ubuntu 14.04 - Python 3.4 UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: 14.04, python, python3, unicode

Recently I've made an update, and I've started getting these errores in some programs (in 2 indicators for Unity, specifically):

```
File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-stickynotes/indicator-stickynotes.py", line 134, 
in showall self.nset.showall(*args)
File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-stickynotes/stickynotes/backend.py", line 143, in showall
note.show(*args)
File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-stickynotes/stickynotes/backend.py", line 70, in show
self.gui = self.gui_class(note=self)
File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-stickynotes/stickynotes/gui.py", line 60, in __init__
self.css_template = Template(css_file.read())
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here are is my locale info:

```
LANGUAGE=en
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=letter
```

Is there a way to configure Ubuntu to solve this, without having to wait for updates of those aplications (if applicable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the solution that I found, which has to do with bugs in each software.

This issue is solved by adding the UTF-8 encoding to specific calls to open files that were missing it, like this example, where

```
f = open(CHANGELOG,'r')
```

changes to

```
f = open(CHANGELOG,'r', encoding = "utf-8")
```